# How to do parametrized queries using pypyodbc in Python?

Tags: python, prepared-statement

I'm discovering Python and is stuck at a error I don't understand.

When querying a SQL Server database with parameters, as I understood from the examples, the way to do it is:

```
import pypyodbc

connectionString = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=VSQL001;DATABASE=Tests;Trusted_Connection=yes'

connection = pypyodbc.connect(connectionString)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('select 1 where ? = ?', [1, 2]);
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

As soon as I execute the following code, I receive the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1171, in prepare
> check_success(self, ret)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 937, in check_success
> ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, ODBC_obj.stmt_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 919, in ctrl_err
> raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
> pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('07009', '[07009] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "\MFRAME\Data\Profiles\Arsene\Desktop\query.py", line 7, in 
> cursor.execute('select 1 where ? = ?', ['1', '2']);
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1398, in execute
> self.prepare(query_string)
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc.py", line 1174, in prepare
> if sys.exc_info()[1][0] == '07009':
> **TypeError: 'DatabaseError' object does not support indexing**

What doesn't support indexing? How should I write the `execute` statement correctly?

Comment: Are you sure your error is being produced by that line, as far as I can tell (apart from having a weird query) that should be valid according to the example  pages found here:https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: @LucasKauffman: I've edited the question to provide the full code (and a full traceback).

Comment: I can't test it at the moment but is your query valid syntax?

Comment: Also why do you have a semicolon there?

Comment: @LucasKauffman: a query like `select 1 where 1 = 2` has nothing wrong; it will simply return an empty result. As for the semicolon, my mistake. Removed it; the same error is still here.

Comment: I get the same thing on your "working" example with a single parameter on Python 3.3, FWIW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played with this a bit and I think there must be a bug in pypyodbc that make it not behave as the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/wiki/Compatibility_with_pyodbc) suggests:

> In most cases, you can simply try pypyodbc in your existing pyodbc
>   powered script with the following changes

For example, I ran this code with `pyodbc` and everything works fine:

```
... import pyodbc as db
... conn = db.connect(connect_string)
... cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> # One parameter
... res = cursor.execute("SELECT 1 WHERE 1=?", [1,])
... print(cursor.fetchall())
[(1, )]
>>> # Two parameters
... res = cursor.execute("SELECT 2 WHERE ?=?", [1, 1])
... print(cursor.fetchall())
[(2, )]
>>> conn.close()
```

But switching the import line to `pypyodbc` breaks the second example:

```
... import pypyodbc as db
... conn = db.connect(connect_string)
... cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> # One parameter
... res = cursor.execute("SELECT 1 WHERE 1=?", [1,])
... print(cursor.fetchall())
[(1,)]
>>> # Two parameters
... res = cursor.execute("SELECT 2 WHERE ?=?", [1, 1])
... print(cursor.fetchall())
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: 'DatabaseError' object does not support indexing
>>> conn.close()
```

So I don't think this is anything you're doing wrong; either pypyodbc is broken for this use case or its documentation is wrong. If I can figure out which I'll file a bug.

Comment: Thanks, it is a bug in pypyodbc that broken under python 3. I have fixed in github. https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/blob/master/pypyodbc.py